# what does "statement with no effect" mean in c?

Tags: c

I'm getting this warning when I try to compile:

```
hw3.c:28:8: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
for(i; i < strlen(userCmd); i++)
```

this is the structure its referencing I think:

```
int main (void) 
{
    char *userCmd;
    userCmd= (char *) malloc(1024);
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    for(i; userCmd[i]; i++)
    {
          if (userCmd[i] == ' ')
          {
             temp = i + 1;
             count++;
          }
    }
}
```

I might be confused but that looks like it should have an effect so I'm not sure the message means what I think it does.

Comment: You're also testing against a buffer you allocate but never populate with data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement with no effect is the first clause of the `for` statement, namely `i;`.  Here the value of `i` is evaluated and discarded, hence it has no effect.

This clause can be left blank if there's nothing to do:

```
for(; userCmd[i]; i++)
```

On a side node, this code probably won't do what you think it will.  Memory returned by `malloc` is uninitialized, so reading the elements of the array is reading *indeterminate* values.

Answer (score 2):

The statement with no effect is the first part of the `for` loop head,

```
for(i; userCmd[i]; i++)
    ^ here
```

Normally you would write `i = 0` or even `int i = 0` in this position, instead of declaring and initializing `i` above the loop.  If you want to get rid of the warning without changing how you declare and initialize `i`, you can leave this part of the loop head completely empty:

```
for( ; userCmd[i]; i++)
```

Note the extra white space.  Normally, whitespace on the inside of parentheses is bad style, but in this case you want it there to make the empty first component more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

> what does “statement with no effect” mean in c?

It means you have a statement in your code that is legal C but does not do anything.

The compiler lets you know because it is very likely a mistake on your side.

Answer (score -1):

just initialize in the for loop for(i=0; userCmd[i]; i++)